# I have a Python/Flask application running with mod_wsgi and apache. If I try to install a new module, it seems not to work. Why is that?

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I have a flask application with a `requirements.txt` file running on a server. I also created a virtual environment with python 3.5 for this application.

This is the virtual host config file:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/example/env/bin/python3.5
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/example/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/example/web>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works.

Now I added a new library `library` to my `requirements.txt` file, I activated the virtual env and rerun the pip3 install command. Apparently everything worked.

But if I try to access my application now, what I get is

```
ImportError: No module named 'library'
```

On my pc it works but I don't use `mod_wsgi` so I'm pretty sure there is some misconfiguration here.

Please not that I can use the new module if I run python from my virtual env.

Comment: can you reach this new module from the python shell after activate the virtual env ?

Comment: Yes, i will update the question with this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/example/env/bin/python3.5
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/example/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

use:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/example/env
```

Read the documentation on configuring mod_wsgi for a virtual environment. Your current configuration is wrong. The documentation explains what you should be using.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Also recommended that you use mod_wsgi daemon mode instead of embedded mode.

Comment: Update your question with the configuration you are now using so can see if you switched to daemon mode as also suggested. Also, what version of Python is mod_wsgi compiled for? From the command line Python, if you go ``import library; print(library.__file__)`` what does it display?